# HighCharts: show alla y axis on tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I created a chart based on http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

When mouse is hovered on a column, it shows the value of the hovered y axis and total value.

I'd like the tooltip to show values of all 3 y axis, with their respective color, regardless of the y axis that was hovered.

I know it must be done in the following code, but how do I access other y axis from it? Is it possible to do something like `{series[0].point.y}`? Nothing I tried worked.

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
},
```

Comment: How is this set up? Because hovering a column only relates to one y-axis, right? Or what?

Answer (score 4):

Use the option

```
    tooltip: {
        shared:true
    },
```